# How to maximize a multi-variable equation?

Tags: math, equation

I have an equation like

```
eq1 --> a1*X1 + a2*X2 + .... an*Xn + b1*X1*X2 + b2*X2*X3 + ... bn-1Xn-1*Xn + c
```

that I want to maximize and/or minimize it so that the other equation

```
eq2 --> d1*X1 + d2*X2 + .... dn*Xn + e1*X1*X2 + e2*X2*X3 + ... en-1Xn-1*Xn + f = 0
```

is placed.

X1, X2, ..., Xn are variables (more than 10 variables) and a, b, c, d, e, f are some numbers (coefficient). Also we know that the first equation is larger than "0" and less than a number like "Y". but we don't know what is the exact minimum and maximum!

Comment: What makes you think it must be bounded either above or below?

Comment: the variables are the same in the second equation, so there are some solutions (some values for X variables) for the second equation but we cannot count them (the space is huge), based on those solutions maximize the first equation. Also we know that the first equation is larger than "0" and less than a number "Y".

Comment: This belongs on the [math.se] site.

Comment: Interesting question, this is an example of constrained optimization in which the objective function is a quadratic and the constraint is some other quadratic. That both objective and constraint are differentiable makes the problem a lot easier (not easy, but easier ...). A web search for "quadratic programming" should turn up some resources.